# ReplaceAll that works inside Rational?

Tags: replacement, syntax

I'm trying to replace all instances of a `31632259` in a formula with `x`, but there's something special about how Mathematica handles rationals, so straightforward `ReplaceAll` only replaces some instances. What's the simplest way to accomplish the replacement below?

```
formula = (2 (16019583 + Sqrt[12871387612913]))/
    31632259 + ((31632259 + Sqrt[12871387612913])^(4/
         3) z)/(31632259 19087^(2/3) 12871387612913^(1/6));
formula /. {31632259 -> tempVar}
```

$$\frac{\left(x+\sqrt{12871387612913}\right)^{4/3} z}{31632259\ 19087^{2/3} \sqrt[6]{12871387612913}}+\frac{2 \left(\sqrt{12871387612913}+16019583\right)}{31632259}$$

(This comes out when using `Solve` by replacing all symbolic values with prime numbers, adding this information through `Assumptions` is sometimes not enough to make `Solve` succeed)

Comment: `Rational` objects are atomic so you can't access its parts directly. You could use `Numerator` or `Denominator` to access the relevant parts.

Comment: `31632259` is a factor of `12871387612913`. Do you want the factor replaced, too?

Comment: Yes, that would be handy (I'm currently adding additional replacement rules like /.(val1*val2->var1*var2))

Comment: Why not replace symbolic values with symbolic constants like E, Pi, Khinchin, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
formula = (2 (16019583 + Sqrt[12871387612913]))/
   31632259 + ((31632259 + Sqrt[12871387612913])^(4/3) z)/(
   31632259 19087^(2/3) 12871387612913^(1/6));

ToExpression[
   StringReplace[ToString@InputForm@formula, 
    a : DigitCharacter .. /; 
      Divisible[ToExpression@a, #] && a != "0" :> 
     "(" <> ToString[ToExpression[a]/#] <> "*" <> ToString@#2 <> 
      ")"]] & @@ {31632259, tempVar}

formula == % /. tempVar -> 31632259
```

---

$$\frac{\left(\text{tempVar}+\sqrt{406907}
   \sqrt{\text{tempVar}}\right)^{4/3} z}{19087^{2/3}
   \sqrt[6]{406907} \text{tempVar}^{7/6}}+\frac{2
   \left(\sqrt{406907}
   \sqrt{\text{tempVar}}+16019583\right)}{\text{tempVar}}$$

```
(* True *)
```

If you do not want to replace also factors inside numbers then use:

```
StringReplace[ToString@InputForm@formula, 
  a : DigitCharacter .. :> (a /. 
     "31632259" -> "tempVar")] // ToExpression
```

---

$$\frac{\left(\text{tempVar}+\sqrt{12871387612913}\right)^{4/3}
   z}{19087^{2/3} \sqrt[6]{12871387612913}
   \text{tempVar}}+\frac{2
   \left(16019583+\sqrt{12871387612913}\right)}{\text{tempVar}}$$